# How to detect TabBar change of SliverPersistentHeader in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have `SliverPersistentHeader` in `DefaultTabController`.

DefaultTabController has 2 Widgets in `TabBarView`.

```
      return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TabBarView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: Sizes.size20,
                    right: Sizes.size20,
                    left: Sizes.size20,
                    bottom: Sizes.size28,
                  ),
                  sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: TopRanking(
                      rankingList: widget.rankingList,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: WeekPersistentTabBar(),
                  pinned: true,
                ),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: Sizes.size10,
                  ),
                  sliver: SliverList.builder(
                    itemCount: widget.rankingList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return RankingTile(
                        index: widget.rankingList[index].index,
                        userAvatar: widget.rankingList[index].userAvatar,
                        userName: widget.rankingList[index].userName,
                        userPoint: widget.rankingList[index].totalPoint,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: Sizes.size20,
                    right: Sizes.size20,
                    left: Sizes.size20,
                    bottom: Sizes.size28,
                  ),
                  sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: TopRanking(
                      rankingList: widget.rankingList,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: WeekPersistentTabBar(),
                  pinned: true,
                ),
                SliverList.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.rankingList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return RankingTile(
                      index: widget.rankingList[index].index,
                      userAvatar: widget.rankingList[index].userAvatar,
                      userName: widget.rankingList[index].userName,
                      userPoint: widget.rankingList[index].totalPoint,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Each TabBarView has `SliverPersistentHeader` delegate.

It is `WeekPersistentTabBar` and it has two tabs.

```
 class WeekPersistentTabBar extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
        border: Border.symmetric(
          horizontal: BorderSide(
            color: isDarkMode(context)
                ? Colors.grey.shade900
                : Colors.grey.shade200,
            width: 0.6,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: TabBar(
        indicator: const BoxDecoration(),
        labelColor:
            isDarkMode(context) ? Palette().iconPurple : Palette().ocPurple,
        unselectedLabelColor:
            isDarkMode(context) ? Colors.grey.shade500 : Colors.grey.shade600,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
        splashBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          Sizes.size20,
        ),
        tabs: const [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "This Week",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: Sizes.size18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Last Week",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: Sizes.size18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement maxExtent
  double get maxExtent => 60;

  @override
  // TODO: implement minExtent
  double get minExtent => 60;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I need to know whenever user clicks This Week or Last Week tab in SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate from parent class.

Please help me.